# Jooq mock fetchInto

Tags: kotlin, mocking, jooq

As i found it is possible to [mock](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/tools/jdbc-mocking/) result of jooq request . But is it possible to mock fetchInto function for example?

I have this code

```
val addressSaved = dsl.selectFrom(address)
        .where(address.CITY.eq(city))
        .fetchOneInto(Address::class.java)
```

And I want to mock just fetchOneInto. It will make testing more easily I think.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Anyway the easiest way is to create a repository with a method that contains this select and the mock the repository method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to mock `xyzInto(Class<E>)` methods

You can replace the implementation of all the `xyzInto(Class<E>)` style methods using a single SPI: The [`RecordMapperProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/RecordMapperProvider.html) as documented here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider/

That way, irrespective of your specific query, you can always populate custom implementations of your `Address` class (or even some other subclass). You'll still need to mock the statement itself, though. Probably again using a [`MockConnection`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/mocking-connection/) as you already discovered.

#### Mocking vs integration testing

You've probably made an informed decision regarding mocking vs. integration testing already, but for future visitors of this question, I'm still mentioning this:

In general, it is a lot easier and more useful to just integration test your code with your actual database (e.g. using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org)), and if you must mock things to test higher level logic, then mock your services, not jOOQ SQL statements.